# job class is not accepting the argument send from controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-5

Error: Missing argument 1 for App\Jobs\ReorderDatabase::handle() is showing,
 I need to pass the variable from controller and i need not to use the model,
 so How I should proceed.

My controller function code is here

```
    public function postData(Request $request)
    {

    $updateRecordsArray = Input::get('order');

    $this->dispatch(new ReorderDatabase($updateRecordsArray));

    return Response::json('Okay');
    }
```

My job RecorderDatabase job code is

```
<?php namespace App\Jobs;
 use App\Http\Requests\Request;
 use App\Jobs\Job;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
 use App\Http\Controllers\DragDropController;

 /**
 * Class ReorderDatabase
 * @package App\Jobs
 */
class ReorderDatabase extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle($updateRecordsArray)
{
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordID) {


        DB::table('venues')->where('id', '=', $recordID)->update(array('priority' => $i));

        $i++;
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you aren't passing that array as an argument to dispatch, it is an argument to the constructor of the job you are creating a new instance of.

Comment: I am not getting how to do it, can you please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @lagbox mentioned, you need to pass this argument into constructor and not `handle` method.

Your job class should look like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Jobs;
 use App\Http\Requests\Request;
 use App\Jobs\Job;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
 use App\Http\Controllers\DragDropController;

 /**
 * Class ReorderDatabase
 * @package App\Jobs
 */
class ReorderDatabase extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

protected $updateRecordsArray;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($updateRecordsArray)
{
   $this->updateRecordsArray = $updateRecordsArray;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($this->updateRecordsArray as $recordID) {


        DB::table('venues')->where('id', '=', $recordID)->update(array('priority' => $i));

        $i++;
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: when i am running queue:listen , its showing the error invalid argument supplied for foreach

Comment: @Vikash You could then change `$updateRecordsArray = Input::get('order');` into `$updateRecordsArray = (array) Input::get('order');`

Comment: Nabialek  thanks a lot, been banging my head from last 20 hrs, in lack of basic knowledge, thanks a lot, I appreciate for the help of even basic things.

Comment: Hello! I have followed this and getting this error `BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 835:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $nid ]] in class Rogue\Jobs\SendReportbackToPhoenix`. I'm also using the global helper of `dispatch` (dispatch(new ...` instead of `$this->dispatch` and am using Laravel 5.2. Any other thoughts why I would be getting this error?

Comment: This only apply to controllers but any ideas about to dispatch jobs with constructor parameters through the RedisDriver?