# Too few arguments to function App\\Jobs for Laravel job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

everyone.
Could you help me for creating of Laravel Job?

So, I am trying to parse parameters to job from controller.
But I am getting ERROR.

> "message": "Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\PPodcast::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\order-management\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable.php on line 17 and exactly 4 expected",
> "exception": "ArgumentCountError",
> "file": "C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\app\Jobs\PPodcast.php",

[image: PriceCheckerPodcast]

```
public function __construct($product_url, $PROXIES, $start_index, $offset)

{
    $this->PROXIES = $PROXIES;

    $this->product_url = $product_url;
    $this->start_index = $start_index;
    $this->offset = $offset;

}
```

[image: Controller]

```
PriceCheckerPodcast::dispatch($product_url, $PROXIES, 0, 20);
```

I can not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you running the code on a supported version of PHP? You might want to downgrade the PHP version or fix these errors. It is likely tied to a `user_defined_function`.

Comment: The app is running on PHP 8.1.2 and Laravel Framework 8.83.1.

Comment: PriceCheckerPodcast::dispatch($product_url, $PROXIES, 0, 20);

This code is wrong?

Comment: Broken "magic". Step through that code to see how the constructor is actually invoked. Note, as of 8.0 "`call_user_func_array()` array keys will now be interpreted as parameter names, instead of being silently ignored."

Comment: try `$this->dispatch(PriceCheckerPodcast(...));`

Comment: Ambiguous and typo

Comment: Error : `PPodcast`, File : `PriceCheckerPodcast`. Also dispatch with array and wihtout array.

Comment: Maybe this can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690498/job-class-is-not-accepting-the-argument-send-from-controller-in-laravel?rq=4